# How To Get the Range of a Page Using Word Automation

Tags: c#, matlab, automation, ms-word, ms-office

How do you find the range of page n in Microsoft Word using office automation? There appears to be no getPageRange(n) function and it is unclear how they are divided.

Comment: What is the relation to Matlab if I may ask? This seems msword only to me...

Comment: Oddly enough, I am using MATLAB's COM Server routines to create Word documents, as in:

wordApp = actxserver('word.application');
wordApp.Visible = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it from VBA, should be fairly trivial to convert to Matlab COM calls.

```
Public Sub DemoPerPageText()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim totalPages As Integer
    Dim bmRange As Range

    totalPages = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

    For i = 1 To totalPages
      Set bmRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
      Debug.Print CStr(i) & " : " & bmRange.Text & vbCrLf
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Matlab OfficeDoc utility for reading/writing Word contents from Matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15192-officedoc-readwriteformat-ms-office-docs-xlsdocppt

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I don't have the right context for your question, but from looking at the [Office Development docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a9dt54a(VS.80).aspx) it seems as though you have to create Range objects that contain what you want. The "Range Object" section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(VS.80).aspx) says: "The Range object represents a contiguous area in a document, and is defined by a starting character position and an ending character position. You are not limited to a single Range object. You can define multiple Range objects in the same document... [A Range] is not saved with a document and exists only while the code is running."

Comment: This is true, but it is not clear to me how to easily acquire a range for the nth page.

Comment: Yeah, they don't make it especially easy to figure that out from the docs. :(
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.page.aspx has info on the Page object. I still haven't put it all together, but I suspect the Document object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document.aspx) will have a Pages member which gives you an array of the pages, and from that maybe you'll be able to get a Range object.

Comment: nah no pages member. you have stories, paragraphs, sentances and ranges (generic).